# Concat and return Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to figure out how to get a result from the network, persist it and return the reponse body to the Observable.
Like this:

```
@Override
    public Observable<DefaultUserResponse> createUser(CreateUserCommand command) {
        return this.userService.createUser(command)
                .map(defaultUserResponse -> {
                    User user = new User();
                    defaultUserResponse.setUser(user);
                    return defaultUserResponse;
                }).flatMap(defaultUserResponse -> persist(defaultUserResponse.getUser()));
    }

Observable<User> persist(User user) {return null;}
```

Steps:

1. I get a DefaultUserResponse from the server.
2. Transform the command to a User (command = DTO)
3. Persist the user locally.
4. Return the DefaultUserResponse.

How should I proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: What persist(defaultUserResponse.getUser()) returns?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it !

Comment: Why the -1 ? Was I not clear enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Completable](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ru/2015/12/the-new-completable-api-part-1.html) type for your persist method (if you don't care about the returned value(s)):

```
Completable persist(User user) {
    return Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
        //persisting
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you could use `andThen` operator to wait until persisting completes and push your value further:

```
...
.flatMap(defaultUserResponse -> persist(defaultUserResponse.getUser()).andThen(Observable.just(defaultUserResponse)));
```

Or if you still want to use `Observable` for persisting, just use another `flatMap` instead of `andThen`.

Comment: It does not work, since trying to return a defaultUserResponse inside persist is not allowed...

Comment: It's not trying to return `defaultUserResponse` **inside** persist method, it just _chains_ persisting with returning `defaultUserResponse` wrapped into `Observable`.

Comment: I got it, the first time it was unclear - I've edited answer several times, please check it again.